# Delphi routine to display arbitrary bytes in arbitrary encoding in arbitrary language

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-2007

I have some byte streams that may or may not be encoded as 1) extended ASCII, 2) UTF-8, or 3) UTF-16.  And they may be in English, French, or Chinese.   I would like to write a simple program that allows the user to enter a byte stream and then pick one of the encodings and one of the languages and see what the string would look like when interpreted in that manner.  Or simply interpret each string in each of the 9 possible ways and display them all. I would like to avoid having to switch regionalizations repeatedly.  I'm using Delphi 2007.  Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Why do you think it wouldn't be? Please consider asking *that* as your question instead of just asking the yes/no question you currently have.

Comment: There aren't 9 possible combinations. There is only one UTF-8 and one UTF-16. And extended ASCII encompasses many many encodings. Presumably you mean one of the Windows ANSI codepages that aren't in fact ANSI at all! Going to be tricky in a pre Unicode Delphi. Why don't you use a Delphi that does Unicode? How do you plan to display general Unicode text in a D2007 VCL app?

Comment: If this is for your own personal use then don't use Delphi 2007. Do it in Python. It's a one-liner. Or any other similarly capable tool.

Comment: In Delphi prior 2007 there is WideString and Tnt Unicode controls.
And components like HTMLViewer might make use of those and have subroutines for text conversion.

Comment: David: I am using Delphi 2007 because we have tens of thousands of lines of code in place, and switching to a different Delphi would be too complex.  Michael's answer, below, explains how to do it.  It works, although there are still some things that need ironing out.

Answer (score 7):

In Delphi 2009 or later, this would be easier, since it supports Unicode and can do most of this transparently. For older versions, you have to do a bit more manual work.

The first thing you want to do is convert the text to a common codepage; preferably UTF-16, since that's the native codepage on Windows. For that, you use the [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) function. For UTF-8 to UTF-16, the language doesn't matter; for "extended ASCII", you will need to choose an appropriate source code page (e.g. Windows-1252 for English and French, and GB2312 or Big5 or some other Chinese code page - that depends on what you expect to receive). To store these, you can use a WideString, which stores UTF-16 directly.

Once you have that, you have to draw the text somehow - and that requires you to either get a Unicode-capable control (a label is likely sufficient), or write one, or just call the appropriate Windows API function directly to draw - and that's where it can get a bit messy, because there are several functions for doing that. [TextOutW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145133.aspx) is probably the simplest choice here, but another option would be [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx). Make sure you explicitly call the W version of these function in order to work with Unicode. (See also the related question [How do I draw Unicode text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840719/how-do-i-draw-unicode-text)).

*Take note*: Due to CJK unification - the encoding of equivalent Chinese Hanzi, Japanese Kanji, and Korean Hanja characters at the same code points in Unicode - you need to pick a font that matches the expected kind of Chinese, traditional or simplified, in order to get expected rendering. To quote a somewhat related post by [Michael Kaplan](http://www.siao2.com/2005/06/18/430507.aspx):

> What it comes down to is that there are many characters which can have
>   four different possible looks:
>
> - **Japanese** will default to using MS UI Gothic (fallback to PMingLIU, then SimSun, then Gulim)
> - **Korean** will default to using Gulim (fallback to PMingLiu, then MS UI Gothic, then SimSun)
> - **Simplified Chinese** will default to using SimSun (fallback to PMingLiu, then MS UI Gothic, then Batang)
> - **Traditional Chinese** will default to using PMingLiu (fallback to SimSun, then MS Mincho, then Batang)

Unless you have a specific font you want/need to use, pick the *first* font in the list for the language variant you want to use, since these are standard fonts (on XP, you will need to enable East Asian Language support before they are available, on Vista and above, they are always included). If you do *not* do this, then Windows may either not render the characters at all (showing the missing character glyph instead), or it may use an inappropriate fallback (e.g. PMingLiu for Simplified Chinese) - the exact behavior depends on the API function you use to render the text.